# Create a copy of a table mysql

Tags: php, insert

I am trying to create a copy of a table using the code below. Everything is working great IF they both have the Same Columns. My table1 has 2 columns (id, username), while table2 has 3 columns (id, username, date). My goal is to create a copy of  table1 WHERE `table1`.id = $id AND INSERT the `date` on in it. Can someone guide me with this?

INSERT table2 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE `table1`.id = $id

Comment: quick and dirty, add the date col afterwrds

Comment: rather then SELECT * just select the two columns. Unless I am missing.

Comment: It won't let me insert because they don't have the same columns numbers

Comment: 0_o What do you mean by "the same columns numbers"? Do you mean that the data types are different? Then cast appropriately.

Comment: table1 has columns (id, username), while table2 has (id, username, date)

Comment: So? Insert the two columns from table1 into the corresponding columns in table2. What's stopping you?

Comment: It is not letting me insert since table2 MUST be correspond to table1 which only contain 2 columns.

Comment: That's absolutely not true. Look at the documentation for `insert` statements in whichever RDBMS you're using.

Comment: It is giving me an error (Column count doesn't match value count at row 1)

Comment: Then change your `insert` statement so that you're only inserting into the first two columns of table2.

Comment: How would you actually do that?

Comment: Well, [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) The one line of code in your question is not valid SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
Table1 is ID,Name,DateAdded
Table2 is Name,ID,DateOriginallyAdded,SomeOtherColumn
```

Query would be say

```
Insert Table2(Name,ID,DateOriginallyAdded) Select Name,ID,DateAdded From Table1 Where ...
```

Specify both sets of columns, you could get away with

```
Insert Table2 Select Name,ID,DateAdded,Null From Table1 Where ...
```

or

```
Insert Table2(ID,Name,DateOriginallyAdded) Select * From Table1 Where ...
```

but it can lead to some nasty bugs.

Answer (score 0):

sounds to me like you are looking for a left join of table 2s date onto table 1 only where the ids match... run this query first and you should see it selects the appropriate result set for you:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.date
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id
```

then you can export or INSERT that result set as you please as a new copy of table1

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `"INSERT INTO"`, I suspect you're looking for something like this?

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id, username)
SELECT id,username FROM table1
```